# HSV to RGB conversion

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Based on my question, MosGeo answered with following code. I thank him for his reply.

```
% Load and Convert
RGB_original = imread('peppers.png');
HSV_original = rgb2hsv(RGB_original);

% Modify in HSV
HSV_Modified = HSV_original;
HSV_Modified(:,:,3)= HSV_Modified(:,:,3)*.5;
HSV_Modified(HSV_Modified(:,:,3)>1) = 1;

% Revert Back to RGB and Show
RGB_Modified = hsv2rgb(HSV_Modified);
% Note: RGB_Modified is a uint8 (not double)

% Show Results
figure('Color', 'White')
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(RGB_original)
title('Original')
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(double(RGB_Modified))
title('Modified')
```

My doubt is converting only particular values in V-plane and not the entire V-plane values.
For example
If instead of

```
HSV_Modified(:,:,3)= HSV_Modified(:,:,3)x0.5;
```

we write

```
HSV_Modified(HSV_Modified(:,:,3)>0.8) = HSV_Modified(:,:,3)x0.5;
```

the output RGB image is not as what we expect.

Kindly clarify my doubt.

Comment: I don't know who MosGeo is, or what your previous question was. Please explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish here and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
HSV_Modified(HSV_Modified(:,:,3)>0.8) = HSV_Modified(:,:,3)x0.5;
```

cannot work because what is on the right hand side of the `=` has more values than what is on the left hand side. You want to do this:

```
V = HSV_Modified(:,:,3);
mask = V>0.8;
V(mask) = V(mask)*0.5;
HSV_Modified(:,:,3) = V;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But after using the code                                                                             
V = HSV_Modified(:,:,3);
mask = V>0.8;
V(mask) = V(mask)*0.5;
HSV_Modified(:,:,3) = V;                                                                      
 when we convert back the modified hsv image to rgb image, it is not working properly. I want to convert the modified hsv to rgb such that it doesnot affect the non modified region.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Please update your question with information about why it is not working properly. What do you see, and what do you expect to see? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and apply that!